# Proper meaning of the slang "Baby"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, slang

- Let him do it because it's his **baby**.
- Don't push this job on me because it's your **baby**, not mine.
- This classic show car is his **baby**.
- Hey **baby**, how are you doing today?

I understand that the speaker used the word **baby** to describe **work** in the first and second examples. The 3rd example is confusing me. How can a car be one's work? Please help improve my understanding.

I know the slang word **baby** means "a woman who is young", as in the last example, someone is talking to a woman/girl.

Comment: "Baby" has a dozen different meanings, but the most common are a) a small child, b) a metaphor based on the meaning "small child", and c) a young (and presumably sexually desirable) woman.  Your first three examples are utilizing the metaphor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've slightly misinterpreted the word *baby* in your first three examples.  It means something in which one has invested time, interest, and emotion and for which one has a proprietary feeling.  Speaking hyperbolically, it's as though the object of interest is like one's own child.

I thought I should add an example of the usage that didn't involve work- or job-related situations.  This turned out not to be as easy as I thought.  There's even a canonical political cartoon, showing Hoover turning over the problems of the Depression to Roosevelt in 1933, captioned "It's his 'baby' now":

[image]

But I finally found a story about a man who as a hobby, salvaged his car that had been in an accident, replacing the metal body with one made entirely of wood.  From that [story](http://www.autoevolution.com/news/be-a-real-lumberjack-drive-a-wooden-toyota-pickup-84693.html):

> So, he started salvage [sic] spruce wood from construction sites, adding up
>   bit-by-bit to his truck every evening after work for about nine
>   months. So you can say **it’s his baby now**.

A labor of love, with a play on the nine-month "gestation" period for the "baby."

Comment: Just going to point out that it can, as shown in your examples, emphasize a personal responsibility more than a particular interest. (The question didn't, itself, include that; For sake of clarity, I mention it.)

Answer (score 6):

***[Baby](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/baby)*** in the first three sentences means:

> - Slang An object of personal concern or interest:

while in the last one it refers to:

> - Sweetheart; dear. Used as a term of endearment.

(AHD)

The term [baby](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=baby&allowed_in_frame=0):  (Etymonline)

> - dates back to the late 14c., *babi a diminutive of baban.*
> - ***As a term of endearment*** for one's lover it is attested perhaps as early as 1839, certainly by 1901; its popularity perhaps boosted by baby vamp "a popular girl," student slang from c. 1922.

- From which, probably, its  slang usage to refer to an object of concern or interest.